# Microsoft Dynamic CRM Plug-In debug

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I am programming plug-in for MS Dynamic CRM. Is it possible to debug my plug-in when CRM Server is located on remote computer.

Answer (score 4):

At a high level you'll need to do the following:

1. Copy your .DLL into the CRM Server\server\bin\assembly folder
2. Register the plugin for 'On-disk Deployment'
3. Install and configure the Visual Studio Remote Debugger
4. Attach to the Remote Debugger from Visual Studio
5. Trigger the event

An in-depth explanation can be found here:
[How to remote debug Dynamics CRM plugins and workflow assemblies](http://weblogs.asp.net/pabloperalta/archive/2010/12/01/how-to-remote-debug-dynamics-crm-plugins-and-workflow-assemblies.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I connected to remote debugger, but it didn't help me:( I check breakpoint in any plugin class, but I can't to reach that. What I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list for MS Dynamics CRM 2011:

1. Build the plugin in Debug mode
2. Register your plugin (keep in mind, that if your plugin project is based on other, custom dll-s, you have to merge them with IlMerge into a single dll - Either way, you will have a dll and a pdb file in the output folder)
3. Register the plugin using the Plugin registration tool. (Do not forget the step)
4. Start msvsmon (you can download if from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40781)) as an Administrator on the server
5. Copy the pdb file to the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\server\bin\assembly folder
6. Do an iisreset
7. Open a session for the server (Connect to CRM from a browser)
8. Connect to the remote debugger from Visual Studio (w3wp is the service you have to connect to, if there are multiple service sessions, connect to all of them)
9. Trigger the plugin you registered.

Worked for mw flawlessly many times. (Be sure, that there aren't anyone else trying to use the same server, while you are debugging it, as the server will not respond until you release the code.)

Answer (score 0):

If the installation and usage of the Visual Studio Remote Debugger is not possible, which would be the case for most production systems, you could use the Plugin-Profiler.

It will collect information which will enable you to debug the plugin locally (with limited capabilities, as it is basically a replay of the plugin execution).

See [Analyze Plug-in Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh372952.aspx)

This assumes you are using Dynamics CRM 2011

Answer (score 0):

Here is one another guide how to debug the plugins:

http://inogic.com/blog/?p=61

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very best step by step way to debug your dynamic crm plugins.

http://guruprasadcrm.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-debug-crm-2011-online-plugin.html